# Bitrix. Добавить множественное поле

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день :)
Дали задание на создание модуля,а суть работы модуля заключается в определении схожих товаров и записи ссылок всех похожих товаров в товар. 
Но в самом начале столкнулся с "Добавить множественное поле «Похожие товары» в инфоблок «Товары» для хранения ссылок на похожие товары".
Но "Множественное поле" в св-вах инфоблока я не нашел.
Где его искать?)

Answer (score 0):

Может, так попробовать у свойства инфоблока?

[image: Множественное свойство у bitrix]

Comment: Да,спасибо,оно)